# what does the following statement mean?

Tags: java, ant

In the http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-HelloWorldWithAnt.html

```
echo Main-Class: oata.HelloWorld>myManifest
md build\jar
jar cfm build\jar\HelloWorld.jar myManifest -C build\classes .
java -jar build\jar\HelloWorld.jar
```

Note: Do not have blanks around the >-sign in the echo Main-Class instruction because it would falsify it!

Anyone know why there is such Note. I do not see any difference when we hae balnks around >-sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, it makes no difference.  Not sure what the message on the tutorial means.

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess.

It probably meant to stress the need for getting the line correctly copied. [Main-Class attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/appman.html)

Any value other than `'Main-Class:'` will fail the jar creation.

With a white space after - `Main - Class` or 
just before :  '`Main-Class  :`  gives the error `invalid header field name`: ..